# Neo4j http Cypher query illegal character '{'

Tags: neo4j, cypher, fiddler

I am attempting to query Neo4j using a cypher query in http. I'm using Fiddler to write and send the request. Here is an example of a very simple query I've attempted.

```
POST http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit
Accept: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Type: application/json
{ "statements" : [ { "statement" : "MATCH (n) RETURN id(n)" } ] }
```

No matter what, I get this error:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Illegal character VCHAR='{'
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *head* of an HTTP request must be separated from the optional *body* by an empty line.

In your example, there is no empty line before the body. If that example shows exactly what your request looks like, then that would be an error.

Comment: Haha! Fiddler was reformatting the request for me, putting additional header fields after the body. I moved things around and now it's working. I should've spotted that. Thank you so much.